# How does many-worlds theory explain Bell's inequality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, bells-inequality

How are the correlations in the experiment proposed by John Bell explained by [many-worlds theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation)?

I understand that the assumption of a measurement having a single outcome, is not supported by many-worlds. And hence it may violate Bell's inequality.

But it still has to explain why correlations occur when the experiment is performed.

It would be helpful if the answer is in the context of [this experiment setup](https://cp3.irmp.ucl.ac.be/%7Emaltoni/PHY1222/mermin_moon.pdf), which has 1 particle source, 2 detectors, 3 switches and 2 possible outcomes for every measurement. How does many worlds explain (in the mentioned experiment) that when switches are in same position, the measured outcome is equal, but when switches are different then the outcome is random.

Comment: The correlations occur because quantum mechanics says they have to occur.

Comment: The correlations occurs because they were intentionally correlated. That was the point of Einstein’s thought experiment. If the two particles aren’t perfectly correlated what’s the point of the experiment? The thought experiment doesn’t work if the two particles aren’t on perfectly opposite trajectories and perfectly in phase, etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bell's inequality occurs in the statistical spread of multiple possibilities. Its implication for the many-worlds theory is therefore in the statistical spread of the (events which spawned their) new universes.

Thus, each world retains local realism and the nonlocal aspect of quantum theory manifests only in the spawning pattern of the new universes.

Bell's theorem shows that the statistical distribution of quantum measurements will differ, depending on whether reality is local or nonlocal. For example if you have pairs of entangled photons and measure their polarisations under certain conditions, the statistical distribution of polarizations will differ depending on the nature of reality. We all know that reality has been measured in this way and has shown itself to be nonlocal.

According to the many worlds interpretation, on each measurement the world divides. By the end of the experiment you have followed a long chain of world-divisions. The statistical nature of that chain is just the nonlocal distribution which we all know and love. But in each individual world, every photon and every polarization is locally real. Nonlocality influences only the statistics of world-division, not anything else.

Comment: This would be valid for every Quantum measurement process. Here non- locality or contextuality are relevant. I think that the question concerns these aspects in relation, if any, with the  MW interpretation.

Comment: I am not sure how "Its implication for the many-worlds theory..." can be regarded as valid for every interpretation. Still, I have added a further clarification.

Comment: @GuyInchbald I now understand that the implications would be in a statistical measure over all possibilities. Can you explain further how 'non-local aspect of quantum theory would manifest only in the spawning pattern of new universes'?

Comment: Took more space than I hoped. Any clearer now?

Comment: @GuyInchbald I have been trying to understand some good explanations of Bell's Theorem and I found this [by David Mermin](https://cp3.irmp.ucl.ac.be/~maltoni/PHY1222/mermin_moon.pdf) . Can you help me understand the many worlds result in the context of that - With the setup of 2 detectors, 3 switches and 2 possible outcomes for every measurement.

Comment: @YashSharma Bell's theorem predicts that over many measurements, the statistical pattern of results will be different, depending on whether reality is local or nonlocal. In the many-worlds theory, each individual measurement creates a new universe for each possible result. Bell's theorem therefore predicts the statistical pattern of new universes.

Comment: @Guy Inchbald, I am now clear from your explanation that in case of MWI, Bell's theorem predicts the statistical pattern of the new universes.
One last doubt, in your last sentence you say  'Nonlocality influences only the statistics of world-division, not anything else.' Do you mean non-locality in a different sense than 'One object directly influences another without affecting anything in between '? I am finding it difficult to think of non-locality applicable on a statistical distribution rather than on a single event.

Comment: The quantum wave equation is well known to model the statistical probabilities of the various possible measurement outcomes. Nonlocality occurs when a single equation describes properties of two or more entangled particles; when a measurement or similar event collapsing the wave takes place, it instantaneously affects the properties of each entangled particle. That is what quantum nonlocality is. The MWI interprets this as creating new worlds for each and every possible outcome - in accordance with Bell's theorem, natch.

Comment: `We all know that reality has been measured in this way and has shown itself to be nonlocal.`

Gonna have to disagree with this. One of the major attractions of many worlds is to have a way to keep locality WITH bells' inequality..

Comment: @TKoL Looks like you stopped reading before my final paragraph.

Comment: In a philosophical sense doesn’t this just shunt the burden one “level” up of reality? Generally reality should be taken to mean all that exists. In this case of MWI there is a new reality one level up - that of the many worlds (instead of just one world). Although the one-world is local, the complete reality is still nonlocal (since the world division is nonlocal)..